# "Unbounded" is not visible in Ada

Tags: ada, gnat

I am just a beginner in Ada,

my code looks like this,

```
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure final is
Input : Unbounded.String;

begin
null;

end final;
```

When i compile this code with gnatmake,
compiler gives error `"Unbounded" is not visible"`, what does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `use` clause for `Ada.Strings.Unbounded` makes declarations inside that package directly visible. It does not make the package name itself (`Unbounded`) directly visible, so any reference to the name `Unbounded` that's not preceded by a `.` is going to be incorrect.

Furthermore, the type is called `Unbounded_String`, not `String`.

Change this:

```
Input : Unbounded.String;
```

to this:

```
Input : Unbounded_String;
```

(And please indent your code.)

Comment: I think you mean `Input : Unbounded_String`

Comment: @egilhh: You're right. I assumed that the code in the question was more correct than it was. (It's been a while since I've seriously used Ada.)